# How to organize my Python Libraries using Anaconda / pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, libraries

I am relatively new to Python and I was told to use Anaconda and create a virtual environment (as I am mainly using pytorch for neural networks). But I start losing track about all my libraries.

First of all, I am sometimes not sure, how to install a library - should I use conda install (if so, I have difficulties finding the exact command) or should I use pip install. Also there is a difference between pip3 install and pip install, but for some applications it matters and for others it doesn't. I also start getting conflicts between packages and I don't know how to fix it.

In short: Do you guys have ideas for efficiently organizing your libraries with or without Anaconda? I am happy for any advice.

Comment: _should I use conda install (if so, I have difficulties finding the exact command) or should I use pip install._ When working inside of a Conda environment, install packages with Conda whenever possible. Using pip in the environment requires particular care, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Comment: _Also there is a difference between pip3 install and pip install, but for some applications it matters and for others it doesn't._ I believe they refer to different Python installations versions, it shouldn't matter when using Conda. _I also start getting conflicts between packages and I don't know how to fix it._ I don't think there's a universal solution to that.

Comment: In any case, this is likely off-topic for Stack Overflow, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see what library and modules you are using you can check it with pip3 if you are using python3 and pip if you are using python2. so pip3 freeze gives you a list of installed libraries and also pip3 list. is giving you installed modules.

but for organize your library and modules. i recommend you install virtualenv on desktop and then you can install Django near that folder in desktop so you will control all your modules easily and when you will upload it on sever you will upload with all modules what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure but i think this module will helps you with that too.
https://pypi.org/project/organize/